# How to get list of all Lightning Components present in my org?

Tags: soql, lightning-aura-components, lightning, query, lightning-experience

I am not able to get the id and names of all the lightning components of my org. Is it possible to get them in a list either by querying or any other piece of code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make SOQL request for AuraDefinition and AuraDefinitionBundle objects. There is information about all lightning objects in platform.

First try to do it using developer console where you can see all fields.